# Using the Chef CI toolset, when working within an environment JSON file, how do I use the value of one property to build up another one?

Tags: continuous-integration, chef-infra, devops

In part of an environments JSON file in Chef, I have something like this:

```
        "app_name": {
            "base_url": "//host.name.co.uk",
            "base_api_url": "//host.name.co.uk/api",
        },
```

Whereas I would prefer something such as:

```
        "app_name": {
            "base_url": "//host.name.co.uk",
            "base_api_url": "${app_name.base_url}/api",
        },
```

Another words, avoiding repeating strings that make up other ones, so if the host name changes, all derived properties would auto-update, as well as apps more portable between environments and less prone to human error as things like this would need manual updating.

Cheers,

James

Answer (score 0):

This is not directly available as JSON is a static markup language. You could write your environments file in Ruby instead (note: Chef Zero will only support this in 12.10, which comes out later this month) but it would still statically interpolate at upload time which wouldn't take in to account other overrides. Check out https://coderanger.net/derived-attributes/ for a more generic solution, but it requires recipe code changes.